# Ada - Is there a function to make a character or unbounded string to lower case?

Tags: ada

Is there a way to accept user input whether it is a character or an unbounded string and convert it to lower case?

```
newLine, N: unbounded_string;
M: string(1..26);
len: integer;

new_line; new_line;    
put("What is your favorite color?");
new_line;
put("Answer:");
get_line(newLine);
get_line(M,len);
N := to_unbounded_string(to_lower(M));
put_line(N);
```

And for my input: If i type `BLUE` the `put_line(N);` will return `blue@�hw�`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Character` and fixed length `String`, there is `Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower` [RM A.3.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-3-2.html)

Also, similar function exists for `Wide_Character`, `Wide_String`, `Wide_Wide_Character` and `Wide_Wide_String` in `Ada.Wide_Characters.Handling`and `Ada.Wide_Wide_Characters.Handling`

Comment: So for character I would use Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower. And for unbounded strings i use Wide_Character or what i was using originally

Comment: No, `Unbounded_String` is not the same as `Wide_Character` or `Wide_String`

Comment: You could use `Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower` for a fixed length `String` and convert to an  `Unbounded_String`

Comment: Thanks this worked! But i having some left over garbage data for the ending of the unbounded string because the string did not use all the 26 characters which was declared. Is there a way to remove the garabage data from the unbounded string?

Comment: `My_String(1..26);` before you convert to `Unbounded_String`

Comment: My_String(1..26) is how i declared it. But for example not i ask user for input i do get_line(My_String) and the user input "hello". Now after the hello there is a bunch of random characters. When i convert it to unbounded string i just want the hello to be there

Comment: There is no `Get_Line` procedure with only one parameter. The second parameter is called `Last`. Guess what it returns... Or read about it here [RM A.10.1](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html)

Comment: Yea i know it return the length of the input. But when i convert it using the to_unbounded_string function it still has some extra random characters im not sure why

Comment: Then how exactly are you converting?

Comment: I added the code I used + the output im getting with a test case

Comment: Right. So why aren't you using the len value before converting?

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont understand what you mean. Isnt the length of the string already stroed in len when the statment get_line(M,len); is executed

Comment: No, `len` is an _out_ parameter. It will return the number of characters filled into `M` by `Get_Line`. You have declared M to be a `String` of 26 characters. That will never change. Please read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Strings) and [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/array)

Comment: I took a look at those but dont see what your trying to tell me.

Comment: `N := to_unbounded_string(to_lower(M(1..len)));` However, you _really_ should understand basic array operations and fixed-length strings before jumping to more advanced topics like unbounded strings.

Comment: Thank so much this worked. Yes, I will do as you said.

Answer (score 2):

```
with Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Strings.Maps.Constants;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

procedure Change_Case is

   S : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Enter a string: ");
   S := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String(Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
   Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Put_Line(S);
   Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Translate(S, Ada.Strings.Maps.Constants.Lower_Case_Map);
   Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Put_Line(S);
   Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Translate(S, Ada.Strings.Maps.Constants.Upper_Case_Map);
end Change_Case;
```